# what are the rules around using self to refer to the current instance in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I got a bug in a bit of a complex part of a rails app and was curious when you need to use self to refer to the current object in a Rails model. I had (with the problematic lines beneath and commented out):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
....
def item_instore_enabled_changed list_is_instore_enabled # would be true or false
  if item_is_instore_enabled
    Rails.logger.info("this will be true with is_enabled_item: #{is_enabled_item}")
    self.is_enabled=true if self.is_enabled_item
    # is_enabled=true if is_enabled_menu_item - this didn't work
  end
  Rails.logger.info("BEFORE item save and is_enabled: #{is_enabled}")
  self.save! 
  # save  - didn't work
  Rails.logger.info("AFTER item save and is_enabled: #{is_enabled}")
end
```

Basically, I had to specify `self.is_enabled` rather than just `is_enabled` to assign a value and also could just call `save!` and had to call `self.save!`.

What are the rules for referring to self within an object or was there some other bug causing a problem with the above code?

Comment: thx for comment - I used to always write with self. - but acknowledge that is longer. So when I `save` or `save!` nothing happens so not getting an error. Also, this is being called from another class so possibly self is the other class (which would be nasty)?

Comment: `is_enabled = true` should not work. If you were checking against it - i.e. `if is_enabled == true ...`, that should work correctly. But `is_enabled = true` should always need a `self` because Ruby has no idea if you're setting an attribute on the model or if you're defining a local variable.

Comment: Personally, I *always* use `self`. There are a lot of things that Ruby does implicitly that are really nice. But this is one area where I think being explicit is just much more clear and saves you a lot of potential headaches in the long run.

Comment: hmm... thx - that seems to be it. so it would seem like any assignment would require self?